# count after summarize in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to find the total number of `species` for each `size` after the filter statement. I tried using again the summarise statement but was not able to do it.

```
library(dplyr)
x <- iris
x$size <- cut(iris$Petal.Length,breaks = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),include.lowest = T)

y <- x %>% 
  group_by(size, Species) %>% 
  summarise(n = n())%>%
  filter(n >2)
```

What is the way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way -

```
library(dplyr)

x %>%
  count(size, Species) %>%
  group_by(size) %>%
  summarise(n = sum(n[n > 2]))

#  size      n
#  <fct> <int>
#1 [1,2]    50
#2 (2,3]     0
#3 (3,4]    15
#4 (4,5]    42
#5 (5,6]    32
#6 (6,7]     9
```